# if τ is the finite-closed topology, the discrete topology or the trivial topology then the semi-open sets are precisely the open sets.

Tags: general-topology

A subset $A$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is said to be semi-open if there exists an open set $O \in (X, \tau)$ such that $O \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{O}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the discrete topology, all subsets are semi-open and and all subsets are open. So the equivalence is trivial.

If $X$ is trivial, only $O=\emptyset$ and $O=X$ are possible, and in both cases $A$ is forced to be $\emptyset$ or $X$ too.

If $X$ is the finite-closed (cofinite) topology, then any non-empty semi-open set is cofinite (it contains a cofinite set) and hence open too; the reverse is true in any space.